# Visual Studio Authoring Extensions (VSAE) not visible in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I have installed System Center Visual Studio Authoring Extensions (VSAE - download link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30169 ) multiple times and its not showing up in Visual Studio Enterprise 2019. I am using x64 version with Windows 10 Operating System. I also tried installing through elevated command prompt, still the same issue.

How do i install this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to restart visual studio then type `management pack` to search the project template:
[image]